# Modifying jquery each function via reference

Tags: jquery

This shouldn't actually be too hard, but I don't get it to work. So here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. Yes, I do need an each construct.

```
var test = "<div><ul><li>liste 1</li><li>liste 1</li></ul></div>";

$("li", test).each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("test")
})
console.log(test);
```

Result:

```
<div><ul><li>liste 1</li><li>liste 1</li></ul></div>
```

Antizipated result:

```
<div><ul><li class="test">liste 1</li><li class="test">liste 1</li></ul></div>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Sorry, unless you want `test` to contain a dom collection rather than a string, you won't be able to do this effectively with jquery. You could turn it into a dom collection then convert it back with .html(), but you can't guarantee that it will always return the same html due to differences in html parsing between browsers. if test CAN be a dom collection in the end, simply wrap the original string in `$()` and it'l work.

Comment: It doesn't work because `$("li", test)` converts `test` into a dom collection and you aren't assigning that collection to the `test` variable after you are done, therefore `test` is still the original string.

Comment: Which part? *"simply wrap the original string in `$()` and it'll work. "*?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the context method on a string, only on a collection, you have to use find()

```
$(test).find("li").addClass("test");
```

If you're not really working with elements, but strings, you could still do something like :

```
$(test).find("li").addClass("test").end().get(0).outerHTML;
```

and get the changed string back

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HUxC4/2/)

Comment: well, that would be one answer, but it still does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/HUxC4/

Comment: @rapsli - that's because your console logging the same string, and not the changed jQuery collection.

Answer (score 1):

`test` is getting modified however its not being updated.  You can update it with something like:

```
var test = "<div><ul><li>liste 1</li><li>liste 1</li></ul></div>";
$("li", test).each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("test");
   test = $("<div />").append($(this).parent().parent()).html();
})
console.log(test);
```

Comment: I think Kevins solution looks easier.

Comment: @rapsli possibly, but that depends on the outcome you want. It wasn't very clear in your question how important the format of the result was. In your question it looks like you intended for `test` to still be a string when your finished, which trevor's answer does.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a jQuery wrapped set from the string, operate on it, and use it to output your results: `var $test = $(test);` and `console.log($test.html())`. But see KevinB's comment above: the `html()` call isn't guaranteed to return the string with classes added.

http://jsfiddle.net/HUxC4/1/

Answer (score 1):

The answer I'm going with:

```
var test = $("<div><ul><li>liste 1</li><li>liste 2</li></ul></div>");

$(test).find("li").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("test")
})

test = test.html()
```